# How can I get multiple value from checkbox with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

My html code like this :

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="pilih_fitur" value="fitur1">Posisi Kalimat di Paragraf(F1)</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="pilih_fitur" value="fitur2">Posisi Kalimat di Dokumen(F2)</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="pilih_fitur" value="fitur3">Data Numerik(F3)</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="pilih_fitur" value="fitur4">Tanda Petik Dua(F4)</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="pilih_fitur" value="fitur5">Panjang kalimat(F5)</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="pilih_fitur" value="fitur6">Kata kunci(F6)</li>
              <br>
              <li><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ringkas_sekarang()" type="button" style="float: left;border-radius:0px;">RINGKAS SEKARANG</button></li>
              <li>&nbsp;</li>
            </form>
```

And My AJAX like this:

```
 function ringkas_sekarang(){
        var id=$("#select_uji").val();
        var pilih_fitur=document.querySelector('input[name="pilih_fitur"]:checked').value;
          // console.log(id);
          $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"<?php echo site_url()?>/c_index/hitung_knn",
          data: "id="+id+"&pilih_fitur="+pilih_fitur,
          success:function(data) {
          alert( "Dokumen barhasil diringkas !");

            $("#sesudah_ringkas").html("<textarea style='text-align:justify;padding:20px;border:none;font-size:12px;width:48%;height:380px;float:right' readonly >"+data+"</textarea>");
          }
        });
}
```

How can I get all value on checkbox to send in controller?

Comment: @FastSnail I have tried to array but I just get one value if I checked more two value

Comment: you didn't treat your checkboxes as arrays

Comment: just now I tried to give checkbox name `name="pilih_fitur[]"` ,but still didn work @Fred-ii-

Comment: I am so not a JS guy, but seeing this `data: "id="+id+"&pilih_fitur="+pilih_fitur,` tells me that the checkboxes don't have id's, howeve id's require them to be unique, so TBH I don't know how you're going to get around this, maybe remove the id declaration. I'm a 99% serverside coder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this and make sure that you have jquery included into the page.

```
var arr = $('input[name="pilih_fitur"]:checked').map(function () { return this.value; }).get();
      console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

change the name with

```
name="pilih_fitur[]"
```

for taking the value simplest way is

```
var arr= new FormData(document.getElementById("from_id"));
```

then

```
$.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"<?php echo site_url()?>/c_index/hitung_knn",
          data: arr,
          success:function(data) {
          alert( "Dokumen barhasil diringkas !");

            $("#sesudah_ringkas").html("<textarea style='text-align:justify;padding:20px;border:none;font-size:12px;width:48%;height:380px;float:right' readonly >"+data+"</textarea>");
          }
        });
```